# Is it possible for 2 sql server 2005 databases to share a read only secondary data file (.ndf file)?

Tags: sql-server-2005

We have a large read only secondary database file.  We have several different copies of the database for development purposes, each of which can have slight differences.

Is it possible that all copies share the same .ndf file?  The .ndf file is identical for each copy of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clever things can be done with copies, replication, log shipping, mirrorring, and whatnot, but ultimately it is not possible for SQL Server database to actually share database files.